# TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Tags: python, python-3.x, ord

I try to implement a AES algorithm in python 3.While implementing this I found an error in ord() function.I just try to convert the code from python 2.3 to python 3.How can I fix the error?
My code line is :

```
key = map(ord, key)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your code and not only one line from it.

Comment: `ord` takes a string and returns an `int`. `ord('a') -> 97` and `chr` is the reverse `chr(97) -> 'a'`. Which do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key variable is already a `bytes` object (`str` in Py2). In Py2, `str` is a sequence of length 1 `str`, so you need `ord` to convert to a sequence of `int`.

In Py3, `bytes` objects are sequences of `int`s from 0 to 255 inclusive. Basically, in Python 2, you needed `map(ord, key)` to convert from `str` to sequence (`list`) of `int`, in Python 3, you don't need to perform the conversion at all unless you need to mutate the sequence, and even then, you can simply do `bytearray(key)` to make a mutable copy of the original `bytes`.

Note that Py2.6+ has the `bytearray` type and it behaves the same as it does in Py3 (a mutable sequence of `int`s), so you could likely write 2/3 portable code by just using `bytearray(key)` everywhere (and it will be faster than `map(ord, key)` to boot).

Comment: Thank you ..it really helps